# Error 1009 when trying to access flashvar

Tags: javascript, flash, flash-builder

I'm trying to send a string from the javascript to my flash file.

Inside the `.mxml` I have this:

```
xmlLocation = (root.loaderInfo.parameters.location) ? root.loaderInfo.parameters.location : "";
```

It crashes at this line and gives me a

`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.`

What I'm sending it is either nothing, or this:

```
function callRecorder(x){
        $("#vidRecorderHolder").html("<span id='vidRecorderDIV'></span>");

        currentVid = x;

        var flashvars = {};
        flashvars.fileName=x;
        flashvars.location = "[location]";

        var parameters = {};
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.name="vidRecorder";
        attributes.id="vidRecorder";

        swfobject.embedSWF("commercialtribe.swf?ID="+Math.random()*100,"vidRecorderDIV","400","400","11.2", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, parameters, attributes);   
    }
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

Instead of 
`root.loaderInfo.parameters.location`
it's

`FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.location`